# SDL2 mouse grab is not working

Tags: events, mouse, sdl

With SDL 1.2 I was using SDL_WM_GrabInput to center the (hidden) mouse on screen. This gave me unlimited turning freedom for a first person shooter. SDL2 no longer provides this function but has SDL_SetWindowGrab. This does not seem to be repositioning the mouse to the center of the screen after each loop (event read). I can turn the player around only 1 and a half times before the mouse has hit the edge of the window and will no longer produce xrel values. Is this a bug or is there another function I should be using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Give [`SDL_SetRelativeMouseMode()`](http://wiki.libsdl.org/moin.cgi/SDL_SetRelativeMouseMode?highlight=%28%5CbCategoryMouse%5Cb%29%7C%28CategoryEnum%29%7C%28SGFunctions%29%7C%28CategoryStruct%29) and [`SDL_GetRelativeMouseState()`](http://wiki.libsdl.org/moin.cgi/SDL_GetRelativeMouseState?highlight=%28%5CbCategoryMouse%5Cb%29%7C%28CategoryEnum%29%7C%28SGFunctions%29%7C%28CategoryStruct%29) a try.

Alternatively recenter the mouse each frame yourself with [`SDL_WarpMouseInWindow()`](http://wiki.libsdl.org/moin.cgi/SDL_WarpMouseInWindow?highlight=%28%5CbCategoryMouse%5Cb%29%7C%28CategoryEnum%29%7C%28SGFunctions%29%7C%28CategoryStruct%29).

Comment: I found there is a problem with SDL_SetRelativeMouseMode on Windows so I have gone with the centering the mouse option. Just to complete the post. At the end of the main loop I use    SDL_WarpMouseInWindow(win, cw, ch); (cw is center width, ch, center height) to center the cursor in the the window win. In the event loop under SDL_MOUSEMOTION i subtract the center of the screen from the current position of the cursor:    mouseMovement+=(cw - e.motion.x)